# Is it possible to pulse on a LED strip as the warp engines do on Star Trek TNG?

Tags: led, led-strip, led-driver

I'm trying to activate a LED strip in the same manner and sequence as that of how the activation of the warp engines on the Enterprise in Star Trek TNG.

When activated the following happens-

1. LED rises in intensity. (hoping to have the rate of this step be adjustable)
2. LED reaches an intense set peak brightness momentarily (a flash just as the engines pulse on the Enterprise as it moves into warp).
3. LED brightness output decreases back down to nominal output.

Is this possible and if so how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Buy suitable LEDs or LED strip and suitable micro-controller and you're away. What's the question? Welcome to EE stack exchange by the way, this is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum or a design house.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I also updated my "question".

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible.

Comment: @Aneikei your question of is it possible is answered: yes. You ask how, which you've also been told: suitable LEDs or LED strip with a suitable micro-controller. If you want someone to design it for you, you'll need to go somewhere other than this site. You'll also need to give requirements for cost, size, brightness, energy use etc etc

Comment: You probably want something *really* bright for the flash or it will be disappointing. :)

Comment: https://www.britmodeller.com/forums/index.php?/topic/234940329-lighting-your-star-trek-federation-models-how-to-programming/

Comment: And the led function you described is typically called a breathing led.

Comment: Neopixel or WS2812-based addressable RGB LEDs are convenient, reasonably bright and easy to program in all kinds of interesting patterns with a simple microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this sort of thing is a microcontroller with a PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) output.  Feed the output pin to a MOSFET, which drives the LEDs.  There are plenty of examples on the web.

For a hobbyist, an Adruino would do it.  For something more compact and lower power, almost any small microcontroller would do.  Being programmable, you can make it do any flashing pattern you want.

Comment: If no spacial diversity is required.  The question leaves that unclear.  But a lot of such projects would use an addressable LED strip, in which case what is sent is encoded data, not raw PWM to all LEDs in common.